# Nuxt nested url directory

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I have this king od structure that should be binded to URLs:

```
/default/tree/index.vue -> URL: /default/tree
/default/tree/apple/index-vue -> URL: /default/tree/apple
/error/index.vue -> URL: /error
/login/index.vue -> URL: /login
```

However, I cannot access default/tree/apple, because NUXT gives me an error that ***This page could not be found***

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this folder structure should produce the URLs you want:

```
pages/
--| default/
----| tree/
------| index.vue (url: /default/tree)
------| apple.vue (url: /default/tree/apple)
```

read here to learn more:

[nuxt file system routing](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#basic-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure should be like that:

```
/default/tree/index.vue -> URL: /default/tree
/default/tree/index/apple.vue -> URL: /default/tree/apple
```